# I am stuck on this part of configuring the virtualbox-ext-pack ubuntu-vm. How do i continue to the next step

Tags: virtualbox

I am stuck on this part of configuring the virtualbox-ext-pack ubuntu-vm. How do i continue to the next step 
Here is the image of the problem

[image: Here is the image of problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move focus to the terminal window and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move cursor to the `<Ok>` interface item and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to proceed.